# error TS2339: Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'User | undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following error `Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'User | undefined'`, I'm trying to validate if the user is admin or not, can you help me to check where is the issue?

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { getCustomRepository } from "typeorm";
import { UsersRepositories } from "../repositories/UsersRepositories";

export async function ensureAdmin(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {

    const { user_id } = request;
    console.log(user_id);

    const usersRepositories = getCustomRepository(UsersRepositories);
    const { admin } = await usersRepositories.findOne(user_id);

    //verificar se o usuario é admin.
    if (admin) {
        return next();
    }

    return response.status(401).json({
        error: "Unauthorized!"
    })
}
```

Comment: my repository points to my entity User, the admin should be referenced with the return of the usersRepositories.findOne(user_id) function, but the error q appears as if the admin field was not in the User class and this, what can it be? any settings?

Comment: the problem is that await usersRepositories.findOne(user_id) can eturn undefined. So undefined cannot have "admin" prop inside. In case you admit undefined, you should not use destructuring assignment.